# Swing: Reliable way to be informed about mouse hover position

Tags: java, swing

I am looking for a reliable way to be informed when the mouse moves and when the component beneath the mouse moves. While the first part can be rather easily implemented by using a `MouseMotionListener`, I am currently struggling with the second part.

Right now I have these two ideas:

### 1. Listen for all relevant changes

This one seems to be rather tough, so far I have

- `ComponentListener`: When the component is moved
- `AncestorListener`: When the ancestor is moved
- `MouseMotionListener`: When the mouse is moved

And when a `JScrollPane` is used:

- `ChangeListener`: When the view changes

#### Pros

- Only triggers event based.

#### Cons

- Breaks when `JScrollPane`s are used and you are not aware of it.
- Additionally for my specific usecase I want to implement this hover behavior for a `JEditorPane` and the text layout could change. As described in the comments, for example changing text orientation of a `text/rtf` editor pane by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

### 2. Regularly check position and inform components

Regularly get the mouse position and inform the child component containing this position about it.

#### Pros

- Catches all situations.

#### Cons

- Always triggers, even if no change happened.
- Is not immediate.
- The component lookup is maybe rather expensive, especially with many nested components; I am currently using `Container#findComponentAt` but have not done any tests. (But maybe only as expensive as the lookup for `MouseMotionListener`s.)

---

Do you have other solution ideas, additions or changes to the ideas above?

Comment: Your decent [mcve] code would help a *lot*

Comment: And when given a choice between using an event listener and polling, go with the event listener.

Comment: `Breaks when JScrollPanes are used and you are not aware of it.` - you can listen for ancestorAdded and check if the parent component is a JViewport. `the text layout could change.` - use a DocumentListener for changes in the text and a ComponentListener for changes in the size of the component. Both should cause a repaint.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I only tested the listeners for a `JEditorPane` inside a `JScrollPane`. My goal was rather to ask for other possible solutions or improvement ideas. I currently have not implemented the first idea and was only planning it. Additionally I think it would only make it more difficult to read this question due to the amount of required listeners.

Comment: @camickr good point, I did not think about using the `AncestorListener` for that, but what if I or someone else creates a similar component which uses a viewport (maybe not even a `JViewport` subclass)? For the document changes I was thinking more of style changes (which I could probably detect with other listeners) but also maybe changes to the text orientation (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `O`), which I am currently not able to detect.

Comment: `"Additionally I think it would only make it more difficult to read this question due to the amount of required listeners."` -- providing runnable code, if only for a decent testing framework, would only make the question more easily answered.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels but I want feedback on the concept not on a particular implementation and currently for the listener approach the problems I wrote in the comment to @camickr remain (though I would prefer this approach as well). Or do you want an example which prints to `System.out` every time a relevant event occurs so you can test yourself?

Comment: It sounds like a potentially interesting question, but also smells a bit like the XY-problem. What do you *actually* want to achieve? I mean, imagine you could register a magic `SomethingChangedListener { void somethingChangedAt(Point p); }`, what would this listener then actually do?

Comment: Did you look into [HierarchyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html) and [HierarchyBoundsListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyBoundsListener.html)?